# A few questions about flyback dc-dc converters

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, ltspice, simulation, flyback

I have a few questions regarding this flyback converter simulated in LTspice. 9V was stepped up to 27V using the transformer. My questions are:

1. Why didn't the output voltage change with the change in load? I have seen the use of feedback loop in buck/boost converters just to keep output voltage constant with changing load. But here no feedback is presumably needed.
2. Why are there negative spikes in the pulse generator? The spikes occur when transitioning from 5V to 0V. There are no spikes while going from 0V to 5V. How can the spikes be eliminated?

[image: flyback DC-DC converter]

Comment: The transformer dots should be reversed. The 27-V output voltage is the peak rectification of the 9-V input scaled by the 1:3 turns ratio.

Comment: Also increase the values of the inductances, 1u and 9u for 30 kHz are way too low: if you'll probe the currents in the "primary", you'll see just much current is needed to feed a 1 kOhm load.

Comment: @VerbalKint - you should put your comment as an answer.

Comment: @Verbal Kint thanks mate. I did what you told me to do. The output V changed with load which calls for a feedback loop.

Comment: The mate is happy if he could help! : )